# switching between different quotation marks for output

Tags: python-3.x

how can i get my code to change the quotation marks of my output. i saw some references that mentioned json, but i think i need to write it myself.
so i'll post the question and then my code:

Program: quote_me() Function

quote_me takes a string argument and returns a string that will display surrounded with added double quotes if printed

check if passed string starts with a double quote ("\""), then surround string with single quotations
if the passed string starts with single quote, or if doesn't start with a quotation mark, then surround with double quotations

Test the function code passing string input as the argument to quote_me()

## [ ] create and test quote_me()

def quote_me (word):

```
if word == ("\'"):

    str(word).replace ("\'", '\"')

else:
    return word
```

print (quote_me(input ("what is the sentence: ")))

maybe i've misunderstood what is required as well, if that's the case, please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quote_me(word):
    if word.startswith("\"") and word.endswith("\""):
        word = word.replace("\"","\'")
    elif word.startswith("\'") and word.endswith("\'"):
        word = word.replace("\'","\"")
    else:
        word = "\""+word+"\""
    return word
```

Comment: @issaahmed if this is the correct answer, it should be upvoted.